# Given sales data for a product, what is the best way to calculate the trend period for it?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, trend, test-for-trend

I am looking for a statistical way to calculate an approximate in-trend period for a product from its sales data over a time period.

Of course, in the 'in-trend' period, the sales of the product would be high as compared to the remaining period. But how do I come up with an approximate period for which the product was in trend? Which method/technique should I use?

In the end, I should be able to say something like **"out of 1 year, the product was in trend for approx. 6 months. During this period the sales of the product were relatively high. Before and after this 6 months period, the sales of the product were relatively low."**

**EDIT:
Another way to put my problem, consider below example.
*Let us say there is one industry (say of televisions), people tend to buy a particular television model for only 6 months after that they move to a different model for next 6 months and so on. This is what I want to get at, to find an approximate trend period for a product/industry using sales data. Is there any statistical analysis I can do to achieve this?***

Comment: I've worked with sales trends for decades, but "in trend" is a new one to me (although possibly quite common in your company). You seem to be saying that "in trend" means "sales are good", whereas if it's not "in trend" sales are not good.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @zbicyclist yes, that is what I mean. I am kind of new to do this kind of analysis. This is a very basic question. To be more precise regarding my question, let us say there is one industry say of televisions, people tend to buy a particular television model for only 6 months after that they move to a different model for next 6 months and so on..This is what I want to get at, to find an approximate trend period for a product/industry. Is there any statistical analysis I can do to achieve this?

Comment: @zbicyclist And I would like to confess that I made up the term 'in trend'. I thought that would be cool. :D Anyway, was I able to make myself clear through my comment and edit in the question? Thanks!

Comment: yes, clear. It's possible that you are looking for "turning points" -- points at which the sales trend starts becoming less positive.  This can be analyzed (if the data are clear enough, which they often aren't) using the second derivative. I'll try to look up something more specific, but can't do so at the moment.  A search on this site on "turning point" might suggest some ideas:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=turning+point